# OpenCV 3.0.0 + VS 2015 x64 - frame always empty

Tags: c++, opencv, 64-bit, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I built OpenCV 3.0.0 for VS 2015 in Windows 10 Pro x64.

Then I compiled the following code:

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    cv::VideoCapture capture("Vid_A_ball.avi");

    if (! capture.isOpened()){
        std::cout << "Video Not Opened" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cv::Mat frameReference;
    while (true){
        capture >> frameReference;

        if (frameReference.empty()){
            std::cout << "Capture Finished" << std::endl;
            break;
        } else {
            cv::imshow("video", frameReference);
            cv::waitKey(10);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Video opened correctly, but `frameReference.empty()` is always true.

TIA,
horothesun.